# How to extract text from an Email and put it into a flat file using SSIS

Tags: sql-server, email, ssis, data-extraction

I receive emails which contain paths for files that are stored somewhere. I want to push this paths(text) into a table in some database to keep a record of the file locations. I just want the paths to be in a flat file, so that I can make an SSIS package which will push the data into the required location. If I am able to do this, I can schedule the entire job and automate the process, rather doing it manually every time. There should not be a problem, I guess,  as the structure of the data remains the same always.

Can anyone help me out, how to extract the body of the email and write it into a flat file. There is a Receive Email Task in SSIS, but I am unable to use it.

My Email is in Exchange. And, I am using SQL Server 2012 and Visual Studio 2012.

Comment: I would suggest looking into Script Task. C# code or VB to read lines and write to file.

Comment: I was having that alternate idea in my mind too. There are UI resources in my team who are good in C#. I, even consulted with them. They said, it's possible. But, I was wondering if this can be done through SSIS itself.

But, can you skip the prompt which should come in Outlook, while accessing the files. This is something related to Outlook's security which I read somewhere.